# File traversal vulnerability found on Ubuntu server running a node process using Nessus

Tags: linux, vulnerability, vulnerability-scanners, ubuntu, node.js

I have an Ubuntu server running a normal Node express framework app and a vulnerability was found by a tool called Nessus.

It looks like a pretty standard issue to me, and I will have shell access, but how exactly do I fix it?

```
Nessus was able to retrieve the remote host's password file using the
following URL :

  - http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4000/../../../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd
```

Comment: The most common way of fixing issues like this is to not allow the process which is running the webserver to access anything that's out of the web root.  chroot or something similar should do the trick.  Also, it may be worth confirming that this is indeed a valid result.  Were you able to get to the passwd file by navigating to that URL?

Comment: I actually don't have access to it at all, I will need to arrange a meeting with them to go through it. Thanks for the info though - it will be helpful. I will look into using chroot, thanks again!